# SQL Server 2008 : group table rows together

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 table that I need to group the rows together as sections or groups. Each section begins with the part number 'Group'. I would like to update a field with a code that uniquely identifies each group. I have created a cursor to accomplish this, but I would like something faster. A batch operation would be great and a faster cursor would be acceptable. Thanks

```
USE QuoteWerks

DECLARE @DocNo VARCHAR(30) = 'JHEAQ5947'
DECLARE @validation_code nvarchar(30) = ''
DECLARE @group_code int = 0
DECLARE @part_number nvarchar(30)

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT DI.ManufacturerPartNumber
    FROM DocumentHeaders AS DH
    INNER JOIN DocumentItems AS DI ON DH.ID = DI.DocID
    WHERE DH.DocNo = @DocNo
    ORDER BY DI.ID
    FOR UPDATE OF DI.CustomText14, DI.CustomText03

OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @part_number

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @part_number = 'Group'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @group_code = @group_code + 1
       
        UPDATE DI
        SET DI.CustomText14 = @group_code, DI.CustomText03 = @validation_code
        FROM DocumentHeaders AS DH
        INNER JOIN DocumentItems AS DI ON DH.ID = DI.DocID
        WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE DI
        SET DI.CustomText14 = @group_code
        FROM DocumentHeaders AS DH
        INNER JOIN DocumentItems AS DI ON DH.ID = DI.DocID
        WHERE CURRENT OF myCursor
    END  

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @part_number
END        

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Comment: Please show us your table schema, some sample data and the expected result in `text` and not `image`

Comment: Until you provide some further information, I have no idea how you want it. But sounds like you need to use `row_number()`. Check that out